# how the previous block details comes in corda

Tags: corda

The vault contains data extracted from the ledger that is considered relevant to the node’s owner, stored in a relational model that can be easily queried and worked with.If both exists on same node, is it that the vault database is something that we have access to  (vault data) and not the distributed ledger (but only  by means of internal API for Corda).

Answer (score 0):

You can think of the entire distributed ledger in Corda as being a combination of everyone's segmented view of the ledger. For example, if on a particular network, Node A and Node B were to transact, these two would each hold representations of the states involved in the transaction in each of their vaults.

If Node C and Node D were to also transact, likewise they would store the states relevant to their transaction. If the network were comprised entirely of just Nodes A, B, C and D then together all these states would form the entire distributed ledger with each node holding only the states relevant to them.

Each node can access their own segment of the distributed ledger by querying for data from their vault.